# Edittext loses style when align_baseline used

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles

I have a layout where I have `RelativeLayout` with some `Edittext` which use the default style and are baseline aligned with some `Textfield`. The issue is the `Edittext` are losing the default Holo Light style line (the line under the text). If I take out the baseline then the line is shown though, of course, the `Edittext` loses the alignment.

I suspect this is bug or at least a very strange behavior, but I will give it a try by asking here in SO :-)

This is how it looks (Edittexts are the blank spaces to the right of Opens and Closes TextViews):

[image: layout]

This is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="50"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/store_name_edit"
        android:hint="@string/store_name"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/store_code_edit"
        android:hint="@string/store_code"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/store_group_edit"
        android:hint="@string/store_group"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/store_type_edit"
        android:hint="@string/store_type"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/store_address_edit"
        android:hint="@string/store_street"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="20dip" 
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="@string/store_description" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/opening"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:text="@string/store_opening_hours" />

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/opens"
            android:layout_below="@id/opening"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:text="@string/store_open" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/opens_edit"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/opens"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/opens"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/closes"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/opens"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/opens_edit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:text="@string/store_close" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/closes_edit"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/opens"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/closes"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:textSize="18sp"  />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is the containing `RelativeLayout` somehow isn't expanding to allow for the lines on the EditTexts to show.

Change the containing `RelativeLayout` to:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="100dp">
```

I realise this may not be the best solution but it's a start. Another option might be to try using `alignParentBottom` instead of baseline on all the "bottom" row elements.

Comment: Thanks @Ken, you nailed it. It was because of the RelativeLayout not expanding to wrap the content. Stupid of me to not check that ^^U

Comment: Just to update, it was not the RelativeLayout not wrapping the content, it was the EditText not calculating its real height when using baseline alignment.